# Using switch inside of equation or value assignment

Tags: java

In **Java**, is it possible to use **switch** inside of some equation or value assignment?

```
String str;
```

The following is an example of a standard way that I am trying to avoid:

```
private String statusName() {
  switch (status) { 
    case 1: 
      return "STATE_IDLE";
    case 2: 
      return "STATE_BUFFERING";
    case 3: 
      return "STATE_READY";
    case 4: 
      return "STATE_ENDED";
    default: 
      return "STATE_UNKNOWN";
  }
}

str = "Status: " + statusName();
```

And this is an example of a desired-like way that I am wondering if is possible (*the "code" has an incorrect syntax!*)

```
str = "Status: " + { switch (status) { 
                       case 1: 
                         return "STATE_IDLE";
                       case 2: 
                         return "STATE_BUFFERING";
                       case 3: 
                         return "STATE_READY";
                       case 4: 
                         return "STATE_ENDED";
                       default: 
                         return "STATE_UNKNOWN";
                     }
                   };
```

Is it possible to do something like that **without** using a separate function?

Comment: I understand [switch expressions](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325) are coming in Java 12.

Comment: It's not a `switch`, but there's `String str = "Status: " + 
        (status > 0 && status < 5 ? new String[] {
          "STATE_IDLE", 
          "STATE_BUFFERING", 
          "STATE_READY", 
          "STATE_ENDED"}[status-1] : "STATE_UNKNOWN");`

Comment: Why not look at making Status an enum, and then you can just get by ordinal if you must. `StatusEnum.values()[ordinal];`

Comment: "that I am trying to avoid" Why?

Comment: @ggorlen - Yeah, that works, but I pitty whoever has to read it after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a map:

```
str = "Status" +
    Map.of(1, "STATE_IDLE", 2, "STATE_BUFFERING" /* etc */)
        .getOrDefault(status, "STATE_UNKNOWN");
```

Of course, you don't have to build the map every time: you can build it once and assign it to a field.

But really, there is no advantage over defining a separate function.

---

The most similar translation of OP's code would be something like:

```
"Status: " + (
    status == 1 ? "STATE_IDLE" :
    status == 2 ? "STATE_BUFFERING" :
    status == 3 ? "STATE_READY" :
    status == 4 ? "STATE_ENDED" :
    "STATUS_UNKNOWN")
```

This checks `status` one-by-one, rather than jumping as in a switch. There are only 4 cases here, so this is unlikely to represent a substantial performance issue.

Personally, I dislike nested conditional expressions in general: they feel a bit too clever for their own good (although this one isn't so bad).

Comment: if u dont mind , can u define your java version. Because in Java8 , there is no `Map.of` method. It'was added in java9.

Comment: Build a map *somehow*. Use Guava's `ImmutableMap.of` if you want. Heck, use double brace initialization if you must (if you can handle the knowledge that a kitten will be butchered every time it runs). The exact API isn't really relevant.

Comment: Of course, you would not build a _map_ for a continuous integer index, but use an array/list, right?

Comment: @AgostonHorvath Map is the correct logical abstraction here, basically for all the reasons described in the *Effective Java* item about using enum maps instead of ordinal indexing. You could choose to implement that map using a list and indexing into it, but only if profiling shows that a plain old map is actually a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @AndyTurner reiterating the same old excuse for writing crappy code there. i've yet to see one project where they in fact went back and did profiling. not to mention profiling has a huge cost, especially when measuring systems with external dependencies. Doing detailed profiling in production systems is also something that is very complex.
And most of all, if you do this approach everywhere, your whole system will be underperforming in general, making it hard to pinpoint one place with a clear & easy performance gain.

Comment: @AgostonHorvath OK, then you could choose to implement that map using a list and indexing into it without profiling. To be clear: I would implement this using a switch in a method; I don't understand the problem that OP is trying to avoid. That's going to be fast, readable, not limited to a contiguous range etc.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood right you want to make String str be a concatenation between the word status and the returned value from the switch statement try this solution it is working for me.

```
String str = "Status";
       switch (status){
           case 1:
               str = str+" "+"STATE_IDLE";
               break;

           case 2:
               str = str+" "+"STATE_BUFFERING";
               break;
       }

    }
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Do you mean to switch on `str`?

Comment: No switch  on an Integer I think this is obvious from the cases